# I can't get the data from database to my view class. When I run my case it closes unexpectedly

Tags: android

Below are the errors in the log cat:

```
10-19 03:18:31.339: D/gralloc_goldfish(1440): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-19 03:20:18.739: I/Choreographer(1440): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-19 03:20:19.429: I/Choreographer(1440): Skipped 333 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-19 03:20:19.629: D/AndroidRuntime(1440): Shutting down VM
10-19 03:20:19.629: W/dalvikvm(1440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ad6ba8)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Process: com.example.first, PID: 1440
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first/com.example.first.ViewThought}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.example.first.ThoughtManager.getAllThoughts(ThoughtManager.java:83)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.example.first.ViewThought.onCreate(ViewThought.java:30)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-19 03:20:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 11 more
10-19 03:25:20.079: I/Process(1440): Sending signal. PID: 1440 SIG: 9
```

When I try to open the view xml after running my code it stops. What is the problem with my code? Please help me.

**CRUD operating class:  here I have all the operations like insert,delete,update etc**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class ThoughtManager {
    private Thought thought;
    private ThoughtDbHelper dbHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private ContentValues contentValues;
    private ArrayList<Thought> allThoughts;

    int iTitle,iDetail,iDate,iReason,icomment,iTime;



    private String[] coloumns=new String[]{ThoughtDbHelper.KEY,ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL,ThoughtDbHelper.TIME,ThoughtDbHelper.DATE,
            ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT,ThoughtDbHelper.REASON};

    public ThoughtManager(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper=new ThoughtDbHelper(context);
        contentValues =new ContentValues();

    }

    public ThoughtManager openForWrite(){

        db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public ThoughtManager openForRead(){
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}

    public long createThought(Thought thought){


        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE, thought.getTitle());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL, thought.getDetail());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME, thought.getTime());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE, thought.getDate());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON, thought.getReason());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT, thought.getComment());

        return db.insert(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }


    public int updateThought(Thought thought){


        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE, thought.getTitle());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL, thought.getDetail());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME, thought.getTime());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE, thought.getDate());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON, thought.getReason());
        contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT, thought.getComment());
        return db.update(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE+"="+thought.getTitle(), null);

        //return db.insert(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteThought(Thought thought){
        return db.delete(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE+"="+thought.getTitle(), null);
    }

    public ArrayList<Thought> getAllThoughts(){

        cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null,null,null,null,null,null);
         iTitle=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE);
         iDetail=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL);
         iTime=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME);
         iDate=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE);
         iReason=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON);
         icomment=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT);



        for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){
            thought=new Thought(cursor.getString(iTitle), 
                    cursor.getString(iDetail),
                    cursor.getString(iTime), 
                    cursor.getString(iDate),
                    cursor.getString(iReason), 
                    cursor.getString(icomment));

            allThoughts.add(thought);
        }
        return allThoughts;

    }

    public Thought getThought(Thought thought){
        cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null,null,null,null,null,null);
         iTitle=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE);
         iDetail=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL);
         iTime=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME);
         iDate=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE);
         iReason=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON);
         icomment=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT);

        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            thought=new Thought(cursor.getString(iTitle), 
                    cursor.getString(iDetail),
                    cursor.getString(iTime), 
                    cursor.getString(iDate),
                    cursor.getString(iReason), 
                    cursor.getString(icomment));
        }

        return thought;
    }
}
```

This is my view class which contains the code to view the data:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class ViewThought extends ListActivity {

    ThoughtManager manager;
    ArrayList<Thought>allthoughts;
    ArrayList<String>allTitles;
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        manager=new ThoughtManager(this);
        allTitles=new ArrayList<String>();
        allthoughts=manager.getAllThoughts();
        //getting all titles
        for(Thought thought:allthoughts){
            allTitles.add(thought.getTitle());
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allTitles));
        listView=getListView();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

This is my xml for viewing the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Error is due to `NullPointerException` at line 83 (`com.example.first.ThoughtManager.getAllThoughts(ThoughtManager.java:83)`) can you mark it?

Comment: public ArrayList<Thought> getAllThoughts(){

        cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null,null,null,null,null,null);
         iTitle=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TITLE);
         iDetail=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DETAIL);
         iTime=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME);
         iDate=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE);
         iReason=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.REASON);
         icomment=cursor.getColumnIndex(ThoughtDbHelper.COMMENT);

Comment: it is the codes in line 83

Comment: somebody . please help me..!!

Comment: public ArrayList<Thought> getAllThoughts(){ cursor=db.query(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null,null,null,null,null,null);

Comment: Debug your app using your IDE tools. Put a breakpoint in that line and check what's happening. Probably either `db` or `ThoughDbHelper.??` is null

Comment: please.. any other opinion??

Comment: @Dhaval Gondaliya: can u help me??

Comment: waiting for a reply..!!